# Do sprite sheets provide any advantage during rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, sprite

Using a sprite sheet for at least each individual animation or even a single big one for all your sprites is generally a good idea because there will be less overhead, compression will be better, and the server won't be bombarded with as many requests. However these benefits all only affect the downloading of ones sprites from the webserver, what about rendering efficiency?

**In short:** Is there any significant benefit in rendering individual frames directly off of the sprite sheet, rather than putting each frame on its individual canvas beforehand and rendering from there?

What I'm planning to do is create an array of frames for each animation, so `frame[0]` would be an off-screen canvas element representing the first frame. I'm not super concerned about memory overhead (though it'd also be interesting to know), I'm mostly concerned about the efficiency of the rendering. If it's a significant performance hit I could consider instead making each "frame" something like an object with a reference to the respective sprite sheet, and `x/y/w/h` values for where to find the frame on the sheet.

**PS:** I'm asking this with canvas in mind, would it be different for webGL?

Comment: I think extra canvases don't make any significant difference in rendering performance. However, given their memory usage, I'd consider them unncessary. A reference to the sprite sheet sounds like a much better idea.

Comment: @Bergi: I could still have my API expect individual frames, then simply put them all together onto a sprite sheet internally. Would keep the API the same way I originally intended it, but improve the internal implementation. I was gonna clone the frames anyways so they'd be protected from (accidental) outside influence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect @Bergi has it just right.

I did the following quick perf test drawing a sprite 10000 times using canvas-frames and then using clips from a spritesheet.

On my machine (win8/2GHz/4Core), clipping from a spritesheet was always faster, but **both canvas-frames and spritesheet-clipping occurred so quickly that there was no significant rendering speed benefit using one method or the other.**

Given no speed improvement between the 2 methods, we're left with Bergi's good conclusion that the extra setup plus memory overhead with canvas would tilt a decision towards clipping a spritesheet. Also, the canvas-frame solution would certainly lag on mobile--mobile doesn't do canvas well.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var cframes=[];
var iw,ih,iw10;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/avatars.png";
function start(){

  var iw=img.width;
  var ih=img.height;
  var iw10=parseInt(iw/10);
  var iterations=10000;

  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=iw10;
    c.height=ih;
    cx.drawImage(img,  iw10*i,0,iw10,ih,  0,0,iw10,ih);
    cframes.push(c);
  }


  var t1=performance.now();
  for(var i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    ctx.drawImage(cframes[i%10],10,0);
  }
  var t2=performance.now();


  var t3=performance.now();
  for(var i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    ctx.drawImage(img,  (i%10)*iw10,0,iw10,ih,  10,ih,iw10,ih);
  }
  var t4=performance.now();

  alert(iterations+' draws. Canvas-frames:'+parseInt(t2-t1)+'ms, spritesheet-clips:'+parseInt(t4-t3)+'ms');

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: black; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Very good answer! On my machine (win7/2.6ghz/4core) with a crappy onboard GPU the difference is usually between 3 to 5 milliseconds, which is actually pretty significant considering the whole thing takes only 15-20ms total. That and saving on memory overhead definitely make using sprite sheets for final rendering a better option. +1 and accepted